# Centering contents seems not to work

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, horizontal

I am trying to create a rather unusual table.  The problem seems simple but I could not fix it although I have been trying for a week.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\begin{tabular}{|*{29}{P{0.1cm}|}}
        \hline
        \Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

As can be seen, the letter "A" is pushed to right side. I would like it to be in the box (cell).
I appreciate any ideas that may help me understand the problem.

To illustrate further:

[image]

Here, the code is the same but letter size is \tiny, with an additional row. Why aren't the letters in the center?  Where is that "space" between the left wall of the cell and the letter "A" coming from?

Comment: The letter A in `\Huge` font size is a lot wider than just 0.1 cm.

Comment: Also, you can't fit 29 huge A's next to each other in a single line.

Comment: Something that comes closer to the desired output could be `\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \noindent\begin{tabular}{|*{29}{>{\Huge}c|}}
        \hline
        A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A& A\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}`. However this is 167 pt wider than the textwidth and thus does not fit onto the page.

Comment: Could you please add a bit of background information on why you want these boxed letters. Probably there is a better solution than using a tabular.

Comment: Hi @leandriis, I am using this type of table to create a set of annotations for a Chinese sentence.  The table will have 4 more rows in fact.  ExPex package seemed to be for this kind of task but it assumes the words have spaces in between; Chinese chars do not have spaces in between in a sentence.

Comment: The problem with the solution you offered is that "c" columns change depending on the content size; However, I would like the "29 column by 5 row fitting in a 5in line" table to be rigid.  I should be able to merge columns/cells but the size each cell represents should never change.  I can use my existing code by changing the left margin of the page because I will not need to show the cell borders.  However, when two chars represent a single word, I do want to highlight bottom borders of a set of cells to show word groups in Chinese.

Comment: The horizontal white space between the border of the cell and the letter can be controlled using \setlength{\tabcolsep}{... } as I did in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Your columns are too narrow, use a `c` columns instead. However, then you will see that the table is too wide for the margins, even if you decrease `\tabcolsep` to 2pt (or to 0pt).

Depending of your options, you may either put the page in landscape mode, using [pdflscape](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdflscape), or rotate the tabular 90 degree. In *Example 2*, I have used `\rotatebox` from the [graphicx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package to set the tabular in landscape mode. You also have to decrease the top an bottom margins to avoid overfull box warnings. I used [geometry](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) for that purpose.

If you need `p` columns, you can calculate the width using `\dimexpr` or using [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). If do not you need multiline cells (i.e. `p`-columns), but all cells must be of same width, you can use [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array)'s `w`-columns and calculate the width.

**Example 1 - `c` columns**

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array}
%\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\begin{tabular}{|*{29}{c|}}
        \hline
        \Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**Example 2 - rotatebox and `c` columns**

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}


\usepackage{graphicx}

%\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\noindent\rotatebox [origin=center]{90}{%
\begin{tabular}{|*{29}{c|}}
        \hline
        \Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}&\Huge{A}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: wow --you just repeated `\Huge{A}`  * 29 times

Comment: @jsbibra I used OP's example, because that was what he asked for! He tried to set an unusual tabular. Do you think that is a reason for downvoting? In my answer, I explained what OP did wrong, and how to solve the problem. and when I wrote the first answer, there was no other answers or comments.

Comment: @jsbibra If you redirect `\Huge` into all columns, you presuppose that all cells in all rows shall be set `\Huge`. OP did not indicate that.